# Hovered text on image with absolute position

Tags: css, image, text, hover

[image]

On image you can see 3 pictures, i want them to be hovered with text.
I'm pretty new in all of this CSS thingies. After you hover on 1 of three image text will appear, my problem is that i tried many thing, maybefault lays in position absolute?

HTML:

```
<div id="imgBackground"></div>
<div id="imgContainer">
    <img src="images/coffee_01.jpg" />
    <img src="images/coffee_02.jpg" />
    <img src="images/coffee_03.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgBackground {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(244,244,244); }

#imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 980px;
    padding: 30px; }

#imgContainer img {
        margin: 0px 14px 0px 14px;
        width: 295px;
        height: 254px;    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys but your answers haven't helped me much.

As you see in this code i tried to scretch a bit what i need, but take attention and move your mouse under the imgage on white space, it also hovering. How to fix this problem?

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:221px;
left:0px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
text-align: center;
text-height: 50px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Here's my update:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5UEW/2/

I think this might cause it, any ideas ?

@edit

This code from my page:

```
.imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 295px;
    height: 254px;
    padding: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.imgWrapper .text {
    position:relative;
    bottom:274px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 295px;
    height: 254px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    text-align: center;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.imgWrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

And result on my page:
[image]

Comment: Nice demo, your fiddle helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="hover" />
    <p class="text">text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

check demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/liccyfuentes/D5UEW/

Answer (score 0):

LOne's answer is correct, but this works without you changing to much.

HTML:

```
<div id="imgContainer">
    <li style="background-image:url('images/coffee_01.jpg')"><p>Some random text here...<p></li>
    <li style="background-image:url('images/coffee_02.jpg')"><p>Some random text here...<p></li>
    <li style="background-image:url('images/coffee_03.jpg')"><p>Some random text here...<p></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgContainer {
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        width: 980px;
        color:#FFF;
        padding: 30px;
}

#imgContainer li {
        margin: 0px 14px 0px 14px;
        width: 295px;
        height: 254px;
        list-style:none;
        background:#000;
}

#imgContainer li * {
        opacity:0; /* Visibility: hidden; works too! */
}

#imgContainer li:hover * {
        opacity:1; /* Visibility: visible; works too! */
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzIGl